# Options for reducing latency in search

Tags: search, solr, architecture, lucene, latency

I am working on a visual search based on search using solr / Lucene.

I'm indexing subtitles to tens of thousands of videos.  As people type and I want actual videos to load and seek to the position found in the subtitles. when you "accept" the results, the "playlist" will play the segments of each video (a few seconds before / after the text match in subtitles).

What steps will I need to take to architect this into a realtime solution (assuming good bandwidth, but web latency (eg 100ms)

For starters, there's the question of storing the actual subtitles with their timing in Lucene.  The recommended way is to just use Solr as an "index" and then download any files yourself. However, this adds another round trip to the server if I have to wait for the results, then download the subtitle file. The other option is to base64 encoded it in a string for example and have solr return it as a field.

Is there any way around that extra round trip without including the full subtitle file in Solr?  This is a key question because I will want to have the actual subtitle file with the seek location before downloading video data.

Other options include using an LSTM language model to predict queries and optimistically start pre-downloading subtitle files, but this will likely end up interfering with the queries themselves.

But the core question here is:

**Can I "send a text document back" along with the Solr response to save a round trip to the server?**

I'm using the Docker solr image, but I'm thinking I can pass the query to a proxy (on same machine as Solr) and do the Solr query "locally", and send back both the response (with highlights for the user to see) and the subtitles document. However, I'd actually want the user to see the text results as instantly as possible, without doubling the data transfer by sending a document too.

In other words, I'd like to send a query, and get back 2 responses in parallel: one with the search results, and the second with the subtitle file.  But I'm not sure I can pull off a 2 part response in javascript like that.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: Since Solr shouldn't be exposed directly to the user anyway, couldn't you retrieve both in your controller? Since you'll need the search result to decide which files to retrieve, you'll need to either put them into Solr as a stored, but not indexed, field, or retrieve from a different source when you get the hit back.

Comment: @MatsLindh I hadn't got that far (only done initial tests with solr), I assumed solr had some kind of permissions with readonly public API.  But that's a good point. I guess it comes down to giving a 2-part http response to an ajax request.

Answer (score -1):

Solr can index and store your full text, whether subtitles or complete reviews. You can configure Solr to highlight the search terms when displaying the results. What is more, Solr is sub-second fast, even for huge (in my world) text volumes.

@MatsLindh yes, Solr should be behind a web app.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Highlighting